# generate makefile for cmake purpose

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, cgal

I use cgal for a personal project and i want to use make to to run CMakesList.txt and build the project.If ind this documentation but i do not quite understand it.
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Unix%20Makefiles.html

What **A hierarchy of UNIX makefiles is generated into the build tree** means and how can i generate a Makefile to run the CMakeLists.txt

Comment: You wouldn't use make to call cmake, but use cmake to automatically create Makefiles, so you can use make ro build your project. I suggest searching for CMake tutorials online, you will find a lot.

Comment: The following part of the documentation is imho a better place to get started: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/user-interaction/index.html#generating-a-buildsystem . Note that you could use `make` after the project generation step to build the project, but I recommend using `cmake` even for building, since the command line interface is independent on the generator used (with some small exceptions).